# $watch not being triggered on array change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to figure out why my `$watch` isn't being triggered.  This is a snippet from the relevant controller:

```
$scope.$watch('tasks', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    //do some stuff
    //only enters here once
    //newValue and oldValue are equal at that point
});

$scope.tasks = tasksService.tasks();

$scope.addTask = function (taskCreationString) {
    tasksService.addTask(taskCreationString);//modifies tasks array
};
```

On my view, `tasks` is clearly being updated correctly as I have its length bound like so:

```
<span>There are {{tasks.length}} total tasks</span>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems like this problem also applies to watching objects. Instead, you must watch a particular property.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Try `$watch('tasks.length', ...)` or `$watch('tasks', function(...) { ... }, true)`.

By default, [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) does not check for object equality, but just for reference.  So, `$watch('tasks', ...)` will always simply return the same array reference, which isn't changing.

**Update:** Angular v1.1.4 adds a [$watchCollection()](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection) method to handle this case:

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for arrays this implies watching the array items, for object maps this implies watching the properties). If a change is detected the `listener` callback is fired.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I have spent hour by not knowing this

Comment: extremely helpful!

Comment: Late to the party, but if anyone is using ControllerAs syntax in this scenario, be sure to add that onto the watch string (the first parameter). For example, $watchCollection('controllerAsName.tasks', .function(...){});

Answer (score 13):

Very good answer by @Mark. In addition to his answer, there is one important functionality of `$watch` function you should be aware of.

With the `$watch` function declaration as follows:

```
$watch(watch_expression, listener, objectEquality)
```

The `$watch` *listener* function is called only when the value from the current *watch expression* (in your case it is `'tasks'`) and the previous call to *watch expression* are not equal. Angular saves the value of the object for later comparison. Because of that, watching complex options will have disadvantageous memory and performance implications. Basically the simpler *watch expression* value the better.

Comment: +1.  I'll mention (for completeness) that the listener function is also called once initially to initialize the watcher.  This needs to happen _even if the `watch_expression` has not changed_.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend trying

```
$scope.$watch('tasks | json', ...)
```

That will catch all changes to the `tasks` array, as it compares the serialized array as a string.

Comment: As a cautionary note, this solution would involve serializing to JSON on every digest cycle, not great for performance (particularly if the object is a complex one, or a long array). It *will* work, but it's a bit of a 'sledgehammer to crack a nut'.

Comment: little performance test for different object sizes would be interesting.

Comment: This set me on the right path to fixing the same problem with objects.

Answer (score 3):

For one dimensional arrays you may use [$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watchcollection)

```
$scope.names = ['igor', 'matias', 'misko', 'james'];
$scope.dataCount = 4;

$scope.$watchCollection('names', function(newNames, oldNames) {
  $scope.dataCount = newNames.length;
});
```