# AngularJS model bound with two fields

Tags: angularjs

I have an object like following:

```
  MyObj{
    Groups:[{name:"test1": xdata:"[1,2,3]"  }, {name:"test2": xdata:"[5,6,7]"  }]
  }
```

I have to represent these values in two different views on the same page. First view renders xData and yData in textareas, it uses SplitArray directive to display values 1,2,3 one value at each line in a text area.

```
 <textarea   split-array="" ng-model="group.xdata"  > </textarea>
```

Second view shows these values in textboxes. xData split into three textboxes like following

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="group.xdata[0]" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="group.xdata[1]" >
```

Following is the SplitArray directive

```
myModule.directive('splitArray', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            function fromUser(text) {
                return text.split("\n");
            }

            function toUser(array) {    
                return array.join("\n");
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);
            ngModel.$formatters.push(toUser);
        }
    };
})
```

When I make a change in view1(textarea) I can correctly see the changed values in second view (textboxes) but when I make a change in view2 the change is not reflected back in the textareas. When I do a console.log on change in textboxes I can see the model shows new values. My question is why the model changes are not being reflected back in textareas, do I need to make some change in splitArray directive?

Comment: I am not sure but you might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363259/watch-not-being-triggered-on-array-change

Comment: please set up a plunkr or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be by design that the `ngModel` doesn't handle objects or arrays. In the [ngModelController code L1085-L1089)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/890e939fcc0e059b66a4868853d82e23fbc68ac3/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1085-L1089), an `!==` operator is used to compare to see if the model value has changed. Since the `$modelValue` is always equal to the value (`xdata`) when `xdata[*]` changes, the `ngModelController` doesn't detect any changes from the model.

However, you can workaround this by adding a watcher in the directive to invalidate the $modelValue whenever the watcher is called.

```
scope.$watchCollection(attr.ngModel, function (newValue, oldValue) {
  ngModel.$modelValue = oldValue;
});
```

Here is a Plunker that demonstrates this workaround: http://plnkr.co/edit/mUL577?p=preview

Another way would be to use the `ngChange` directive on the `input` fields to invalidate the model value. However, that introduces coupling between the directives.

---

There is an issue on AngularJS that is tracking this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2553

Also, the `split-array` directive here is basically doing what [`ngList`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angList) is doing. However, `ngList` doesn't respect the separator on when rendering to view (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2561).