# Angular $watch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using two `$watches` on my controller that are supposed to take an eye at these two objects:

```
$scope.gastos = {
    name: "Gastos mensuales",
    data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo",
                "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre",
                "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]
};

$scope.ganancias = {
    name: "Ganancias mensuales",
    data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo",
                "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre",
                "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]
};
```

Two charts (from the Charts.js and angular-charts plugins) read data from them. I've put the charts in custom directives that receive the data from an attribute, and they're working properly.

The problem is, that I want to create another chart who reads another object that is equal to these, but calculates it's data in this method:

```
function calcularBeneficios(){
 var data = [];
 for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
    data[i] = $scope.ganancias.data[i] - $scope.gastos.data[i];
 }
    console.log("FUNCTION DATA: "+data);
 return data;
}
```

These are the watches (I tried both watching the `object` and the `object.data` variable):

```
$scope.$watch("gastos", function(){
  $scope.beneficios.data = calcularBeneficios();
  console.log("SCOPE: "+$scope.beneficios.data);
});

$scope.$watch("ganancias", function(){
  $scope.beneficios.data = calcularBeneficios();
  console.log("SCOPE: "+$scope.beneficios.data);
});
```

This doesn't work. You see all the `console.logs`? I only see the `"SCOPE" console.log`, once (not even twice for `ganancias`). When I change the data in some inputs that are bound to these two objects, everything works (the charts get real-time updated) but the `beneficios` chart doesn't, aswell these watches just don't work.

Am I doing something wrong at these two watches?

Comment: in the `console.log("SCOPE:")`, is `$scope.beneficios.data` being printed out with its updated value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$watch not being triggered on array change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363259/watch-not-being-triggered-on-array-change)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is is that you are watching the top-level `gastos` and `ganancias` objects. There are two potential issues with this:

1. As the [docs for $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) say, by default, normal JavaScript inequality is used to determine if an object has changed (`x !== y`). As the object itself is the same object, you are just changing data *within* it, this will always be true, so the `$watch` is not fired.
2. You can get around 1. by setting the `objectEquality` flag to true (`$scope.$watch('x', function(){}, true)`). This then does a deep comparison and should pick up differences in the `data` array. However this is much more performance intensive.

As you are just using the `data` array in each object, you can simply use [`$scope.$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) on `gastos.data`. This is cleaner and faster.

Here is a working snippet demonstrating this:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  // same code
  function calcularBeneficios() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      data[i] = $scope.ganancias.data[i] - $scope.gastos.data[i];
    }
    console.log("FUNCTION DATA: " + data);
    return data;
  }

  
  $scope.beneficios = {
    name: "Beneficios mensuales",
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo",
      "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre",
      "Noviembre", "Diciembre"
    ]
  };
  
  $scope.gastos = {
    name: "Gastos mensuales",
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo",
      "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre",
      "Noviembre", "Diciembre"
    ]
  };

  $scope.ganancias = {
    name: "Ganancias mensuales",
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo",
      "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre",
      "Noviembre", "Diciembre"
    ]
  };

  // watch the array collection in gastos.data 
  $scope.$watchCollection("gastos.data", function() {
    $scope.beneficios.data = calcularBeneficios();
    console.log("SCOPE: " + $scope.beneficios.data);
  });

  // watch the array collection in ganancias.data 
  $scope.$watchCollection("ganancias.data", function() {
    $scope.beneficios.data = calcularBeneficios();
    console.log("SCOPE: " + $scope.beneficios.data);
  });
  
  
  // testing functions

  $scope.changeGastos = function() {
    $scope.gastos.data[4] = 10;
  }
  
  $scope.changeGanancias = function() {
    $scope.ganancias.data[0] = 40;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h3>beneficios.data</h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in beneficios.data track by $index">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-click="changeGastos()">Change Gastos</button>
  <button ng-click="changeGanancias()">Change Ganancias</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) instead of `$watch` to watch for a collection.

Or you can also watch like this:

```
$scope.$watch("gastos + ganancias", function(){
  $scope.beneficios.data = calcularBeneficios();
  console.log("SCOPE: "+$scope.beneficios.data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Both work, but only if I aim to gastos.data and ganancias.data. Which should I use, $watchCollection and place a watch for each of them, or that simple $watch?

Comment: You should use `$watchCollection` instead because it should be less expensive than the deep `$watch`. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: You can get more detailed usage of `$watch` & `$watchCollection` at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29189252/2405040. It now depends on your need.

Comment: BTW `$scope.$watchGroup(["gastos", "ganancias"])` is cleaner than `$watch("gastos + ganancias")`