# Parent isolated scope updated only once in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angularjs-directive, scope, watch

I’m trying to update parents scopes variables when `onchange` event is fired in a child custom directive.
The event I’m using in the child directive, which is an `input` file, is `onchange` that triggered by jqLite. That means, 
operation outside Angular scope. For updating the scope I’m using `scope.$evalAsync` function (tried `$timeout` and `scope.$apply` as well). In the parents custom directives I’m using `$watch` function as the listener.

Please take a look in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shimizacken/rowxnvym/17/) full example

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <parent></parent>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('parent', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="parent">Parent' + '<span class="file-name">{{selectedFileName}}</span>' + '<child files="files"></child>' + '</div>',
    scope: {
      files: '='
    },
    link: function(scope){
        scope.$watch('files', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal && newVal.length > 0) {
          scope.selectedFileName = "selected file name: " + newVal[0].name;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('child', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="child">Child<br />' + '<span class="file-name">{{selectedFileName}}</span>' + '<file-upload files="files"></file-upload>' + '</div>',
    scope: {
      files: '='
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$watch('files', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal && newVal.length > 0) {
          scope.selectedFileName = "selected file name: " + newVal[0].name;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('fileUpload', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="file" />',
    scope: {
      files: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.bind('change', function(e) {
        scope.$evalAsync(function() {
          scope.files = (e.srcElement || e.target).files;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

In the example, every time I’m selecting new file, the parents scopes variable `files` are updated perfectly, and its `$watch` function are called.

**The problem is that in Firefox the parents scopes `$watch` function is called only once. Only on the first time.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363259/watch-not-being-triggered-on-array-change), which pointed me that the problem is that I’m using `$watch`.

According to the following explanation:

> By default, `$watch` does not check for object equality, but just for
>   reference

In my case I'm watching an array. The reference of it didn't change, and that's why the `$watch` function was not called. What actually changed, it's only the inner properties of the array. Therefore the solution is to use `$watchCollection()` instead, which:

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of
>   the properties change ... ...for arrays this implies watching the array items

Why `$watch` is not working in Firefox, but working nicely in Chrome and IE? The answer regards to the implementation of the file input `change` event. The fact that Firefox always fires the `change` event, even when uploading same file to it. This is *not* the behavior in Chrome and IE. Because of that, Firefox, apparently, keep same `files` array object on every `change` event, and only changing its inner items. Chrome and IE, apparently, create new `files` object on every `change` event, but will not fire the event when uploading file with the same name.